# Passing user defined variable into get_permalink

Tags: permalinks, variables

I'm trying to use a predefined variable (generated from an earlier sweep of the database) in wordpress' standard [get_permalink( get_page_by_title)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) function.

I'm assuming that this is possible? But I can't get it working, it always returns the url of the current page.

For the sake of clarity below I'm just manually assigning the variable.

Code...

```
<?php $mypagename = "My First Page"; ?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( get_page_by_title( $mypagename ) ) ); ?>">LINK</a>
```

N.B - My First Page (my-first-page) does exist in the database

Any ideas where I'm going wrong or if it's not possible to do it like this do you have any other suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: Try `var_dump( get_page_by_title( $mypagename ) )`. I bet you get `NULL`. That's why `get_permalink` is returning the URL for the current page. Are you sure the "My First Page" page exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_page_by_title()` returns a object by default and `get_permalink()` needs the ID as first parameter. Try:

```
$mypagename = "My First Page";

$permalink = get_permalink( get_page_by_title( $mypagename )->ID );
```

Comment: Ahh that will be why it's not working then ;) Thanks!